# Form freezes when I run my program

Tags: c#, forms

my form freezes immediately when I run my code. I'm not sure why, but please take a look at the code below and see the screenshot. Basically when I run my code, the form freezes once my code loads, and it just says "not responding" what could it be doing?

[image: screenshot of Form]

```
namespace MySample
{


public class Driver
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.Show();
        try
        {

            StartModbusSerialRtuSlave();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }



    }



 public static void StartModbusSerialRtuSlave()
    {

        using (SerialPort slavePort = new SerialPort("COM1"))
        {
            // configure serial port
            slavePort.BaudRate = 38400;
            slavePort.DataBits = 8;
            slavePort.Parity = Parity.Odd;
            slavePort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            slavePort.Open();

            byte unitId = 1;

            // create modbus slave
            ModbusSlave slave = ModbusSerialSlave.CreateRtu(unitId, slavePort);
            slave.DataStore = DataStoreFactory.CreateDefaultDataStore();

            slave.Listen();


        }
    }
}
```

CODE ON FORM

```
namespace MySample
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing ``slave.Listen();`` runs in a continuous loop causing the UI thread to hang. You'll need to have it run in a separate thread.

Comment: i'm new to C#, and this has already been an interesting project of incorporating PLCs and C# together....any suggestions, or methods/examples/theory to investigate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `StartModbusSerialRtuSlave` is not returning. The call to `Listen` likely blocks, which is normally fine, but its on the UI thread.

Because it isn't executing on its own thread (separate from the UI), it causes the application to "lock up" and deliver the error message you see.

Simple fix, don't perform long-running operations on the UI thread. Start things like I/O on their own thread.

For example:

```
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    try
    {
        new Thread((p) => StartModbusSerialRtuSlave()).Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    //Start your form the right way!
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Comment: Hey Bradley, I implemented the code block you suggested above, and when  I step through, the Form appears, and still hangs, and then disappears (closes) after the "new Thread" line of code executes.

Comment: The sample code I gave is a good start. The only caveat is that theres no way to stop it! That should probably be handled by the library though. A call to `Stop` (or whatever) should unblock the `Listen` call and allow the thread to terminate.

Comment: @Pardon_me Do you get an exception in your debugger?

Comment: Hmmmm.....ok well I'll give it a go, thank you for a start in the right direction!

Comment: my debugger isn't displaying any exceptions

Comment: @Pardon_me One other thing to be careful of; your application may be terminating because there is no blocking call at the end. You may want to start with a normal forms app that sets up the UI thread and termination correctly, or look at that code to set up your `Main` function.

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a go and report back with my findings. the problem is i need slave.listen to be reading at all times, but I need that UI form to register as well, I may have to modify the slave class calls to incorporate the ui then. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59314/discussion-between-bradleydotnet-and-pardon-me).

Comment: @Pardon_me If you have more questions, just leave a comment and I'll jump into chat.